# Why footer goes to sidebar area?

Tags: html, css

I think this a noob question and already answered but I failed to find the answer.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJazLw)

I am making a simple 2 column layout. columns are working fine but footer goes to sidebar area if content area is taller than sidebar area.
HTML:

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
}
.group:after {
 clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_2_of_3 {
 width: 66.1%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
 width: 32.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;}
 .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper"> <div class="container">
<div class="col span_2_of_3">
  <div>Sed at ante finibus, porttitor nunc sit amet, interdum tellus. Suspendisse tincidunt lectus a enim tincidunt, quis semper tellus luctus. Mauris ut dui dolor. Donec imperdiet fringilla ornare. Nunc in lectus magna. Curabitur at purus libero. Nunc ultricies scelerisque felis. Proin tristique, odio id pharetra condimentum, metus libero porta lacus, at eleifend justo sapien eu ipsum. Donec vel purus gravida, convallis ligula id, scelerisque urna. In eleifend mattis mauris sit amet pharetra. Praesent eget libero augue. Vestibulum ut justo hendrerit, ornare erat sit amet, tristique augue. Quisque tortor ex, pulvinar sit amet elementum nec, fringilla eu urna. Fusce interdum convallis felis, sit amet posuere nulla ornare a. Quisque quis vulputate lacus. Proin mollis lectus mi, sed egestas nibh mollis in. Sed at ante finibus, porttitor nunc sit amet, interdum tellus. Suspendisse tincidunt lectus a enim tincidunt, quis semper tellus luctus. Mauris ut dui dolor. Donec imperdiet fringilla ornare. Nunc in lectus magna. Curabitur at purus libero. Nunc ultricies scelerisque felis. Proin tristique, odio id pharetra condimentum, metus libero porta lacus, at eleifend justo sapien eu ipsum. Donec vel purus gravida, convallis ligula id, scelerisque urna. In eleifend mattis mauris sit amet pharetra. Praesent eget libero augue. Vestibulum ut justo hendrerit, ornare erat sit amet, tristique augue. Quisque tortor ex, pulvinar sit amet elementum nec, fringilla eu urna. Fusce interdum convallis felis, sit amet posuere nulla ornare a. Quisque quis vulputate lacus. Proin mollis lectus mi, sed egestas nibh mollis in. </div>
  </div>
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
Here is widget content
  </div></div></div>
<footer>
<div class="container">
This is footer content
</div>
</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azyEbb

You forgot to close one div, and your footer needs

```
footer {
     clear: both;
}
```

as well.

Comment: Is it possible to add 'clear:both' in different blank div? `<div class="clearing"></div><footer>footer here</footer>` css: `.clearing{ clear: both;}` ?

Comment: Yes, that would the same. You could also add your .clearing class to your footer - <footer class="clearing"></footer>

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as that from Sirence, just other code:

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col span_2_of_3">
            <div>Sed at a...stas nibh mollis in.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
        Here is widget content
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        This is footer content
    </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: it is tricky! u added a dot in clearfix div and hide it. Is it this?

Comment: Yes. The difference to the solution by Sirence is that the footer does not need to be aware of the floating divs above him. You add the class to the divs you want the floats to be cleared afterwards.